# Square is not moving with Raylib

Tags: c, raylib

My program in C is not working correctly. I am using Mac OS.

My program was made to move the square with the <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys, but the executable does not open when compiled.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "raylib.h"

#define SW 800
#define SH 800

int main() {
    int posX = 0;
    int posY = 0;
    char posX2;
    char posY2;

    InitWindow(SW, SH, "Window");

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        scanf("%c", &posX2);
        scanf("%c", &posY2);

        switch (posX2) {
          case 'a':
            posX--;
            break;

          case 'd':
            posX++;
            break;
        }

        switch (posY2) {
          case 'w':
            posY--;
            break;

          case 's':
            posY++;
            break;
        }

        BeginDrawing();
            ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
            DrawRectangle(posX, posY, 100, 100, RED);
        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}
```

Is this an OS problem or a Raylib problem?

Comment: This is not at all how you can read input. See https://www.raylib.com/examples/core/loader.html?name=core_input_keys

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it and it works, this was really helpful.

Comment: The `scanf` is dedicated for reading data from text streams, not for checking keyboard's state. The input stream is buffered and new data is processed after pressing Enter key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` is inappropriate to read keyboard input because of standard stream buffering and the terminal line discipline.  Thankfully **raylib** takes provides a portable and powerful alternative to read the keyboard state: you can use `IsKeyDown()` with a symbol for the key, such as `KEY_A` for alphanumeric keys and `KEY_LEFT`... for cursor movement keys.  Look at the documentation for more information and examples.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <raylib.h>

#define SW 800
#define SH 800

int main(void) {
    int posX = 0;
    int posY = 0;

    InitWindow(SW, SH, "Window");

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {

        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_A)) posX--;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_D)) posX++;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_W)) posY--;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_S)) posY++;

        BeginDrawing();
            ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
            DrawRectangle(posX, posY, 100, 100, RED);
        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}
```